# Springboot: getmapping returns wrong database values

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, postman

Hi I have a mysql table with the following fields. I can't get the right values by calling the api `/roles` in springboot. Here are my roles files -

**Role.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `role` (
  `role_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role_description` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=50 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `role` (`role_id`, `role_description`) VALUES
(1, 'admin'),
(2, 'hairstylist'),
(3, 'staff');
```

**RoleController.java**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RoleController {
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @PostMapping("/roles")
    public Role addRole(@RequestBody Role role) {
        return roleRepository.save(role);
    }

    @GetMapping("/roles")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Role>> getAllRoles() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(roleRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

**RoleRepository.java**

```
package com.example.hms.springboothms.repository;

import com.example.hms.springboothms.model.Role;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer> {
}
```

**Role.java**

```
package com.example.hms.springboothms.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int roleID;
    private String roleDescription;

    public int getRoleID() {
        return roleID;
    }

    public void setRoleID(int roleID) {
        this.roleID = roleID;
    }

    public String getRoleDescription() {
        return roleDescription;
    }

    public void setRoleDescription(String roleDescription) {
        this.roleDescription = roleDescription;
    }
}
```

However, when I call the roles api using postman, I'm getting a repetition of admin fields in the role table - does anyone know why?

[image]

I'm not sure if it's the hibernate mapping? I tried following [Spring Boot: Reading data using Spring Data JPA returns incorrect values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768135/spring-boot-reading-data-using-spring-data-jpa-returns-incorrect-values)
but it still doesn't get the correct values

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

[image]

here's my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <distributionManagement>
       <repository>
         <id>internal.repo</id>
         <name>Internal repo</name>
         <url>file:///home/thara/testesb/in</url>
       </repository>
   </distributionManagement>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example.hms</groupId>
  <artifactId>springboot-hms</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springboot-hms</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the table, setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `create` or `update`, starting the application, which will auto generate the table, then fill in the content into the table manually and then try to fetch the entries again?

Comment: It doesn't seem problematic, though I would have tried setting `roleRepository.findAll()` to a variable and then the variable to the response,

Comment: @aman the findAll() method returns the admin role only instead of all roles in the table -  admin, hairstylist and staff..it keeps giving me those with id 0

Comment: @Amir I set the ddl-auto to update in my application.yml file. I use a mysql script to run my queries so I will always drop the entire database and recreate the tables all the time

Comment: what is your mysql version? also can you post your complete db configuration?

Comment: This happens when there is a problem mapping the *id* column in db and the *entity*. would you mind adding their respective `@Column` on each field of your entity?

Answer (score 0):

As I have tried to mention on the comment section, try the following:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name=“role_id”)
    private int roleID;
    @Column(name=“role_description”)
    private String roleDescription;

    public int getRoleID() {
        return roleID;
    }

    public void setRoleID(int roleID) {
        this.roleID = roleID;
    }

    public String getRoleDescription() {
        return roleDescription;
    }

    public void setRoleDescription(String roleDescription) {
        this.roleDescription = roleDescription;
    }
}
```